# Capture of 'dateFormatter' with non-sendable type 'ISO8601DateFormatter' in a `@Sendable` closure

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ decoder in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
            return dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) ?? Date()   //warning
        })
```

How do I fix the warning?

> Capture of 'dateFormatter' with non-sendable type
> 'ISO8601DateFormatter' in a `@Sendable` closure

Comment: How about just declaring the `dateFormatter` inside the closure? Can you not do that for some reason?

Comment: Fixed thanks, I just didnt understand what the error means

Comment: Then reading the documentation of [`Sendable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sendable) is probably a good idea.